# How to detect when application is closed by a user in android?

Tags: android, android-ondestroy, application-close

I know that, unlike `onCreate()`, `Application` class does not have a `onDestroy()` method. But I wanted to know when my application is closed (or it is not visible on screen anymore). After all, whatsapp and many more similar chat applications can detect when user has left the app, and can record user's last online time. I want to achieve a similar thing. Also, when the application is destroyed, I want to detach all listeners attached to firebase databse.

I have already seen this question, but the accepted answer there is unreliable. So, what is the workaround for `onDestroy()` for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767617/4168607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are talking about `Application` class (detecting when it is destroyed) - this is impossible, when `Application` gets killed developer shouldn't (and don't) have option for executing own code (as it may e.g. restart app from scratch)

but you are talking about app visibility, probably any `Activity` present on screen - extend `Application` class (and register it in manifest) and use `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` with additional counting code: `counter++` when any `onActivityStarted` and `counter--` when `onActivityStopped`. also in `onActivityStopped` check if your `counter==0`, if yes then all your `Activities` are in background, so app isn't visible on screen (still it doesn't mean that its destroyed/killed)

edit: check out [THIS](https://medium.com/@iamsadesh/android-how-to-detect-when-app-goes-background-foreground-fd5a4d331f8a) example. or inspect supporting class [`ProcessLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.html) (which probably is counting visible `Activities` for you and only calls `onAppBackgrounded` when all are gone)

Comment: I think this works out for me. I will try. Btw, this is the link for androidx [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `onDestroy` callback for it . You should be Doing it in `onStop()` of `ProcessLifecycleOwner` . Upon Application destroy your process will be destroys anyways in idle situation so no need to remove listeners there .

Remove the listeners in `onStop` and attach again in `onStart` . You can configure Application class with `ProcessLifecycleOwner` in a way so that Every Activity gets These callbacks. This is how it should works i guess if app is in background u will pop a notification of new message . Checkout [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.html).